# Luabridge: Returning C++ lifetime managed object

Tags: c++, binding, lua, luabridge

This snipped works for basic types:

```
int CreateBasicObject(lua_State *L)
{
    int ret0;

    lua_pushinteger(L, ret0);

    return 1;
}
```

and in lua it looks like this:

```
local NewObject=CreateBasicObject()
```

How would I go about **returning classes instead of ints**?

```
push(L,&MyObject);
return 1;
```

does not seem to work correctly, lua portion looks like this:

```
self.MyObject=Screen.MyObject();
```

And the error is:

```
attempt to index field 'MyObject' (a number value)
```

Comment: Are you specifically asking about LuaBridge or plain Lua? For what it's worth, I believe that before attempting to use any third party binding solution, one should try to implement at least a few C++ classes using plain Lua C API. This helps get better understanding of how this stuff (which LuaBridge and alike build on) works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [newest LuaBridge](https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge) version you can use `RefCountedPtr` for example:

some C++ definition

```
struct A {};

static RefCountedPtr<A> SomeA() {
 return RefCountedPtr<A>(new A);
}
```

and the binding:

```
luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(L)
  .beginClass<A>("A")
   .addConstructor< void (*) (), RefCountedPtr<A> >()
  .endClass()

  .addFunction("SomeA",&SomeA);
```

now you can return `A` objects safely and pass them to other Lua-bound functions as `RefCountedPtr<A>`

in lua you can then use it like that:

```
local a=A()
--do something with a...

local b=SomeA()
--do something with b...
```

Comment: Hello Dmitry, This is what we already use but want C++ to manage memory so there is no need for a reference counter pointer. Any way to use create a C++ lifetime managed object WITHOUT RefCounterPtr?

Comment: Hi, Grapes. How do you want to pass the objects to Lua? If you want to create them in Lua, you'll have to use the RefCountedPtr, if not, you can just pass them as plain pointers or references, just that you should care yourself that the lifetime of your C++ objects exceeds that of the potential reference of it form Lua.

Comment: Hello Dmitry, I want to call CreateBasicObject() and have that return a raw C++ pointer that would not be garbage collected by lua without RefCounterPtr. is that possible?

Comment: It won't be garbage collected, unless the last reference to that object in C++ is destroyed. I think, it's exactly what you need. For example, if you get that reference out into your C++ code as a return value or an input parameter. Please read the *Shared Lifetime* part of the [documentation](https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge/). One of the purposes of LuaBridge is the liberation of the C++ programmer from lifetime management concerns at the boundary of C++ and Lua. Just don't handle raw pointers, use RefCounterPtr and it won't be garbage collected by accident :).

Comment: Hello Dmitry, we already use RefCountedObjectPtr throughout the program but for a few variables would like C++ to have control over the lifetime of the object. https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge/#c-lifetime but as a return value in a function (like CreateBasicObject).

Comment: I guess I understand what you mean, but show me your code then how you want to create the objects. I guess, the CreateBasicObject function will be called from C++, otherwise, how would you get the instance. Or, maybe you want to have a singleton that will be created from lua, but you want to have the pointer. Then you don't need to return the pointer but just set it to some global object, but that I would discourage doing. 
Can you please elaborate on the scenario, Grapes?