# How do I know where "C2280 - attempting to reference a deleted function" occurs?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm having hard time figuring out which piece in my code causes the error mentioned in the title. The error message in the error list is like this:

```
error C2280: 'Foo::Foo(const Foo &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
    file: vector, line: 1100
```

And the compiler output looks like this:

```
d:\visual studio 2013\vc\include\vector(1100): error C2280: 'Foo::Foo(const Foo &)'
 : attempting to reference a deleted function

e:\testproject\src\foo.h(22) : see declaration of 'Foo::Foo'
this diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function
    'luabridge::luabridge::TypeListValues<luabridge::TypeList<P1,luabridge::None>>
    ::TypeListValues(const luabridge::TypeListValues<luabridge::TypeList<P1,luabridge::None>> &)'

with
[
    P1=Foo &
]
```

To me, this error message says absolutely nothing about where the error occurs. I know it's about a deleted copy constructor (line 22 in foo.h is the deleted copy ctor), but that's it. I'd like to keep the copy constructor deleted as well.

How can I find out the exact occurrence of the error?

Comment: Have you deleted your copy constructor? Show your `Foo` class?

Comment: @MohitJain Yes, as I mention in the text, the line 22 that's referred in the error is the deleted copy constructor.

Comment: If copy constructor is deleted, don't use it. `vector` needs copy constructor to keep Foo instances (use `std::move` is applicable).

Comment: @AlexFarber Yes, I know. The thing is, though, that I have no idea where in the code this happens (i.e. where it's tried to put into a vector) since the compiler error is so, err, "quiet" about it.

Comment: Well the error messages says that it's the copy-constructor of `Foo` that is deleted, so it shouldn't be hard to find the class definition of `Foo`, even in a very large project. The next message even *tells* you to look at the declaration for `Foo::Foo` (and that message even contains a file name and line number).

Comment: It is somewhere in template class (TypeListValues? you should know better) instantiated with `Foo` type.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg As I mentioned, I want it to be deleted - it's on purpose. The thing is, I don't know what code tries to store it in a vector.

Comment: Then check the *next* message. You are using [LuaBridge](https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge), and somewhere in that library there is a vector, and if you want to use your class with LuaBridge then you simply have to accept that the library will store your objects in a vector with all limitations that follows from that (like not being able to have a deleted copy-constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code it is hard to be precise, but perhaps you need to use ref-counted pointers to your objects instead of the objects themselves. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206952/luabridge-returning-c-lifetime-managed-object/16210215%2316210215), for example.